# How do i create a cumulative directory?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

Videos and songs in my computer are scattered across 8 drives and i-dont-know number of directories. How do i create a directory in /home/user that automatically updates the shortcuts of videos on my computer?

Comment: Do you mean you want to automatically create shortcuts to all videos from one directory, not actually *move* them?

Comment: I want to automatically create shortcuts to all videos in all directories (videos are scattered across drives and directories). I dont want to move them.

Comment: All files of *type video* or specified file extensions?

Comment: Either flv, mp4, mp3 or mkv, those are the only extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can periodically run the "maintaining" script below to update the folder with links (e.g. by a cron job or in "Startup Applications", see below).

#### What the script does

The script lists all video files (by extension) from up to 10 different directories (or  drives) and checks if a similarly named link exists in your "library" folder. If it doesn't, it creates the link.

Although you're asking it for video files, this way you can keep a "library folder" of any kind of documents of a certain file type.

It works pretty fast: to update from an almost full disk of 750GB (slow / external), it took me just 4 seconds, so it will not be a big burden to your system.

#### How to use

- Copy the script below into an empty file and save it as `update_links.py`.
- If necessary, set in the head section the file extensions you'd like to create links of. I already set it to:

  ```
  extensions = (".flv", ".mp4", ".mp3", ".mkv")
  ```

  like you mentioned in a comment.

  Also set the path to your folder with the links to the videos:

  ```
  library = "/path/to/your/library_folder"
  ```
- The script takes up to 10 directories as arguments. To run it, use the command:

  ```
  python3 <script> <directory_1> <directory_2> <directory_3> <directory_4>
  ```

You can add the command to your startup applications: (Dash > "Startup Applications" > "Add") or run it by a cron job.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import subprocess

library = "/path/to/your/library_folder"
extensions = (".flv", ".mp4", ".mp3", ".mkv")

def create_links(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for name in files:
            if (name.startswith("."), name.count(".") == 0) == (False, False):
                extension = name[name.rfind("."):]
                if (extension in extensions, os.path.isfile(library+"/"+name)) == (True, False):
                    command = 'ln -s "'+root+"/"+name+'" "'+library+"/"+name+'"'
                    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass

i = 1
while i <= 10:
    try:
        dr = (sys.argv[i])
        create_links(dr)
        i = i+1
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an [union mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount), using [`aufs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/aufs). 
First install `aufs-tools`:

```
sudo apt-get install aufs-tools
```

Add an entry to `/etc/fstab` like so, replacing the paths with appropriate values:

```
none /home/user/Videos aufs br=/home/user/Videos:/media/drive1/Movies:/media/drive2/OtherStuff 0 0
```

Then do:

```
sudo mount /home/user/Videos
```

`~/Videos` should now show the contents of all the other directories as well.